# WhiteListing params in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

This is in regard to white listing params if an array/Hash is passed from GUI.

Below is what i am trying to white list.

1. But is see an error on server side saying that unpermitted parameters.

Note: Orderplaced field is of type JSONB

---

```
private
 def order_params
 #params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :orderplaced => [:itemname => [], :quantity => [], :unitprice => [], :tax => [], :discount => [], :itemtotalprice => [] ])
 params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :orderplaced => [ { itemname: [], quantity: [], unitprice: [], tax: [], discount: [], itemtotalprice: [] }])
#not working with either of the above statements.
 end
end
```

---

Server Side error Unpermitted parameters

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-03 20:00:23 +0530
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", "totalprice"=>"30", "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", "orderplaced"=>{":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe"}, ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}}}, "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"1etU+M03uuTl8wcGij1+qEaSFcp/UvgBu3g/xBh0Hmexm4rA1vtCc1mkIWFsw8XcfC2sz2e9TBSmSBZNA9KiNA==", "commit"=>"Create Order"}
Unpermitted parameters: ::itemname, ::quantity, ::unitprice, ::tax, ::discount, ::itemtotalprice
  Customer Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" ORDER BY "customers"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.0ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("ordertype", "orderplaced", "totalprice", "paymentmethod", "created_at", "updated_at", "customer_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["ordertype", "Home Delivery"], ["orderplaced", "{}"], ["totalprice", 30.0], ["paymentmethod", "Cash"], ["created_at", "2018-01-03 14:30:23.393041"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-03 14:30:23.393041"], ["customer_id", 1]]
   (8.0ms)  COMMIT
```

---

2. If I use `params.require(:order).permit!`  then also i see only first index of values i.e array[0] being passed thru params and saved to DB. How can we get the rest then.

GUI:
[Here is the UI i am using to pass the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtESY.png)

Comment: No images, please. They can not only be difficult to read, but also make it impossible to highlight possible errors/problems.

Comment: I know how to click on links. The point is that you should not include images for the reasons I stated. You should copy the console output and paste it into your question (formatted as code).

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem The point is you should post **text**, not images.

Comment: Sure @jvillian. Will do the same. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Those are still images. I would work on your problem, but I can't cut and paste your parameters. Too bad, I suppose.

Comment: @jvillian. I am so Glad your are out to help me. Thank you so much for your support. I am out from my PC for some emergency issue. Will update by evening IST and notify you.

Comment: Hello @jvillian, I've added the error in text format. It would be great help for my project if these two issues are resolved. Kindly help.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Hello @jvillian, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Right now I'm Working on it... Will notify with the result once done.

Comment: Hello @jvillian, Added the response. Still Luck did not favor it seems... :( Kindly help me in reaching my luck.

Comment: Thank you @jvillian. After making the appropriate front end changes, i could white list the params.

Comment: Great. Please upvote/accept answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your code. First, your whitelisting syntax is incorrect. It should more like:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod, {orderplaced: {":itemname": ["0"], ":quantity": ["0"], ":unitprice": ["0"], ":tax": ["0"], ":discount": ["0"], ":itemtotalprice": ["0"]}})
```

In console, this will give you:

```
> params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod, {orderplaced: {":itemname": ["0"], ":quantity": ["0"], ":unitprice": ["0"], ":tax": ["0"], ":discount": ["0"], ":itemtotalprice": ["0"]}})
 => {"ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", "totalprice"=>"30", "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", "orderplaced"=>{":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe"}, ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}}}
```

There are still two things wrong with this:

1. Your `orderplaced` values are still embedded in hashes all with the key `"0"` (e.g., `":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe"}`), and
2. Your `orderplaced` keys all have a `:` at the beginning (e.g., `":itemname"`)

(Since you're storing `orderplaced` in a JSONB column and this is valid JSON, you could ignore these problems. But, cleaning it up now will save the future you or your colleages heartache down the road.)

You can fix this by doing something like:

```
def orderplaced_params
  order_params[:orderplaced].each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), returning|
    returning[k.gsub(":","")] = v["0"]
  end
end
```

Which, again in console, will give you:

```
> orderplaced_params
 => {"itemname"=>"Potatoe", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}
```

Now, you need to reassemble your fixed order_params. Something like:

```
def fixed_order_params
  order_params.slice(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod).merge!(orderplaced: orderplaced_params)
end
```

Which will give you:

```
> fixed_order_params
 => {"ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", "totalprice"=>"30", "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", "orderplaced"=>{"itemname"=>"Potatoe", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}}
```

I have a feeling this is not the end of the story. Based on your UI (you're still posting pictures! BOO!), I would have expected `orderplaced` to be an array of hashes. Something like:

```
Parameters: {
  "order"=>{
    "ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", 
    "totalprice"=>"30", 
    "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", 
    "orderplaced"=>[
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      },
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Television"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      },
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Cable"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"1etU+M03uuTl8wcGij1+qEaSFcp/UvgBu3g/xBh0Hmexm4rA1vtCc1mkIWFsw8XcfC2sz2e9TBSmSBZNA9KiNA==",
  "commit"=>"Create Order"
}
```

(I assume you want to capture each of those rows shown in your picture as part of your `orderplaced` JSONB column.)

In which case, orderplaced_params would need to look more like:

```
def orderplaced_params
  order_params[:orderplaced].map do |order_line_item|
    order_line_item.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), hsh|
      hsh[k.gsub(":","")] = v["0"]
    end
  end
end
```

And this would give you:

```
fixed_order_params
 => {"ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", "totalprice"=>"30", "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", "orderplaced"=>[{"itemname"=>"Potatoe", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}, {"itemname"=>"Television", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}, {"itemname"=>"Cable", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}]}
```

A few things to note:

- It's "Potato", not "Potatoe".
- You should study the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for formatting your code. Variables are typically underscored, like: `order_placed` instead of `orderplaced`.
- If I'm correct about the array of hashes for `order_placed`, then you'll need to fix your front end to pass the array instead of just the hash.
- You should fix your front end so that your `order_placed` keys are not prepended by `:` (e.g., `discount`, not `:discount`).
- You should fix your front end so that your `order_placed` elements are not embedded in hashes (e.g., `'discount'=>'0'`, not `':discount'=>{'0'=>'0'}`)

Those last two will save you all that `order_placed_params` and `fixed_order_params` business and will allow you to go back to using just `order_params`.

**FOLLOW UP**

To avoid:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each_with_object' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0xc17f808>):
```

Try converting `ActionController::Parameters` to `hash` with `to_h`:

```
order_params[:orderplaced].to_h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), returning|
  returning[k.gsub(":","")] = v["0"]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But stuck at orderplaced_params.

Comment: jvillian, such a good answer, and not even a single upvote! I fixed this. Hope you get more upvotes for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your response.

After making the mentioned changes(Front end code not yet fixed), i see an issue  undefined method `each_with_object' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0xc17f808>
in`orderplaced_params` method.

---

Controller code:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @order=Order.new
    end

    def create
        @order=Order.new(fixed_order_params)
        @order.save
    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod, {orderplaced: {":itemname": ["0"], ":quantity": ["0"], ":unitprice": ["0"], ":tax": ["0"], ":discount": ["0"], ":itemtotalprice": ["0"]}})
        end


        def orderplaced_params
            order_params[:orderplaced].each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), returning|
            returning[k.gsub(":","")] = v["0"]
             end
        end

        def fixed_order_params
            order_params.slice(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod).merge!(orderplaced: orderplaced_params)
        end

    end
```

---

Server Side Error :

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-04 19:21:44 +0530
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"ordertype"=>"Home Deivery", "totalprice"=>"25", "paymentmethod"=>"Online", "orderplaced"=>{":quantity"=>{"0"=>"2"}, ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"20"}}}, "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"e2RyLPkDVmCdxNgSzmK/Ov4dTJmCS1ZiM6G3T4u+8TflUd2UCOwnDU1/usslNQiZSGJdI3hNym14wehV9ClHfA==", "itemname"=>"Battery", "commit"=>"Create Order"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `each_with_object' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0xc17f808>):

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:25:in `orderplaced_params'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:31:in `fixed_order_params'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

---

Front end code for one row: (Rest rows are being added using Java Script by increasing the index value )

```
<tr>
            <td><input id="order[orderplaced][:itemname][0]" name="order[orderplaced][:itemname][0]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="order[orders_attributes][0][quantity]" name="order[orderplaced][:quantity][0]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="order[orders_attributes][0][unitprice]" name="order[orderplaced][:unitprice][0]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="order[orders_attributes][0][tax]" name="order[orderplaced][:tax][0]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="order[orders_attributes][0][discount]" name="order[orderplaced][:discount][0]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="order[orders_attributes][0][itemtotalprice]" name="order[orderplaced][:itemtotalprice][0]" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
```

---

And Your guess is correct !!! I wanted `orderplaced` to be stored in DB in such a way where i could pull out the required Key and its values to display.

Which way storing data would be easier to pull out.

Something which you have shown up:

```
Parameters: {
  "order"=>{
    "ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", 
    "totalprice"=>"30", 
    "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", 
    "orderplaced"=>[
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      },
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Television"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      },
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Cable"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10"}
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"1etU+M03uuTl8wcGij1+qEaSFcp/UvgBu3g/xBh0Hmexm4rA1vtCc1mkIWFsw8XcfC2sz2e9TBSmSBZNA9KiNA==",
  "commit"=>"Create Order"
}
```

or this way

```
Parameters: {
  "order"=>{
    "ordertype"=>"Home Delivery", 
    "totalprice"=>"30", 
    "paymentmethod"=>"Cash", 
    "orderplaced"=>[
      {
        ":itemname"=>{"0"=>"Potatoe","1"=>"Television","2"=>"Cable"}, 
        ":quantity"=>{"0"=>"1","1"=>"1","2"=>"1"}, 
        ":unitprice"=>{"0"=>"10","1"=>"10","2"=>"10"}, 
        ":tax"=>{"0"=>"0","1"=>"0","2"=>"0"}, 
        ":discount"=>{"0"=>"0","1"=>"0","2"=>"0"}, 
        ":itemtotalprice"=>{"0"=>"10","1"=>"10","2"=>"10"}
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"1etU+M03uuTl8wcGij1+qEaSFcp/UvgBu3g/xBh0Hmexm4rA1vtCc1mkIWFsw8XcfC2sz2e9TBSmSBZNA9KiNA==",
  "commit"=>"Create Order"
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError (undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass):`

Being a beginner it is getting difficult for me to understand whats going on.

I understand that is an array issue. But not sure where i went wrong.

```
def orderplaced_params
          order_params[:orderplaced].to_h.map do |order_line_item|
            order_line_item.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), hsh|
              hsh[k.gsub(":","")] = v["0"]
            end
          end
        end
```

Comment: @jvilian, Can you please help me in sorting this issue.